# Is there a way to sort based on condition?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I have friendships modeled as entity friendship with composite key sender and reciever.

Bellow I have current query I use to get friends of a person. I would need to sort the friends using their lastname or firstname. The issue is, with the model I have, I don't know for sure which column is the friend, and which is the user.

What I can currently think of is selecting all friends, and sorting in Java code.

My question is, is there a way to still use pagable for sorting?

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Friendship f WHERE f.key.to.id = :user OR f.key.from.id = :user")
Page<Friendship> findActiveFriendships(@Param("user") Integer user, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`findAll(Pageable)` method which gives you a `Page` and query parameters by default so your repository needs to extend from `PagingAndSortingReposigory`, for your example if you use that method so you can define by query the way to get sorted, for example:  *localhost/entity?sort=lastname,desc*

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html